# Joining two lists of different types and sort them by date

Tags: c#, list

I have a first list of entities like this :

```
public partial class Networking :EntityBase
{

    public virtual int NetWorkingId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual string NetWorkingParam
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual System.DateTime NetWorkingDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

And I have a second list of entities like this:

```
public partial class PrivateNetwork :EntityBase
{
    public virtual int PrivateNetworkId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual int ContaId
    {
        get { return _contaId; }
        set
        {
            if (_contaId != value)
            {
                if (Contact != null && Contact.ContaId != value)
                {
                    Contact = null;
                }
                _contaId = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public virtual Nullable<System.DateTime> DateCreation
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I want to collect these two lists in one and sort all the elements by date.

Is that possible ?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Linq's Union Join OrderBy may help...

Comment: Yes I tried Union, but the problem is how to sort them because they don't have the same field

Comment: You can `Select` both to a common anonymous object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem could easily be solved by using polymorphism; use a common base class or interface for both classes, which has the `DateTime` property you want to sort on.

Example:

```
public abstract class NetworkingBase : EntityBase
{
    public DateTime DateToSortOn { get; set; }
}
```

or

```
public interface INetworking
{
    public DateTime DateToSortOn { get; set; }
}
```

And then make your classes derive from `NetworkingBase` or implement `INetworking`:

```
public partial class Networking : NetworkingBase
{
    ...
}

public partial class PrivateNetwork : NetworkingBase
{
    ...
}
```

or

```
public partial class Networking : EntityBase, INetworking
{
    ...
}

public partial class PrivateNetwork : EntityBase, INetworking
{
    ...
}
```

Do a LINQ [`Union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.union.aspx) or [`Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) and then an [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) on the resulting collection.

Comment: This isn't true (that a common base is *required*); "union" objects can be created - anonymous or named - that can then be ordered on/stored. No need for a common base.

Comment: @pst So then you would end up with a list of anonymous objects?

Comment: I assume he has more entities base on EntityBase. Maybe this date is not relevant to those classes.

Comment: +1: Alternatively if you don't have access to - or can't change - `EntityBase`, then define an interface with the date (and anything else you want) on it and have both classes implement the new interface. Then you can cast both sequences to the interface type and sort on the date member of the interface.

Comment: @AmiramKorach is right, all my entities derives from EntityBase and I don't need Date in the other classes.

Comment: @the_ruby_racer Then make an interface for the classes you need the Date in :)

Answer (score 6):

You can do this, although it's not very pretty, and you end up with an `IEnumerable<object>` so you have to check each item's type before you can use it:

```
IEnumerable<object> sorted = myNetworkingList
    .Concat<object>(myPrivateNetworkList)
    .OrderBy(n => n is Networking
                 ? (DateTime?)((Networking)n).NetWorkingDate
                 : ((PrivateNetwork)n).DateCreation);

foreach (object either in sorted)
{
    if (either is Networking)
        // Networking; do something
    else
        // PrivateNetwork; do something else
}
```

Comment: -1: This is an ugly, hacky solution to a problem best solved with polymorphism. When a third `CafeWifiNetwork` type is added there's nothing - other than the original devs (_famously faulty_) memory - to say this linq & foreach loop need to change. With any of the approaches suggested by @khellang the compiler will force you to write the code correctly. It'll work but it won't pass any code review I'd be part of.

Comment: @Binary There's nothing in common between the two classes - the date properties aren't even the same type, let alone the same name - so creating a common interface isn't really polymorphism, it's just hiding a nasty operation (sorting a list of unrelated objects) away in the classes themselves rather than putting it in the code where the result is consumed. I especially wouldn't name the interface `INetworking` when it contains nothing to do with networking; it's more like `IArbitraryObejctThatHasANullableDateTimeProperty`.

Comment: I heartily disagree. There is some reason the asker wants to  merge the lists and sort them, so conceptually at some level **they are the same thing**. The argument that the dates are "different types" is spurious, `DateTime?` covers both. Finally there is absolutely nothing wrong with having an 'INetworkingCreatedDate` interface with a single member. Even if you are 'just hiding a nasty operation away in classes', it's better _hidden_ there **where the relationship will be enforced by the compiler** than scattered in various _hard to find_ places through out the code base.

Comment: I just see this more as the query deciding how it wants to sort the objects, rather than the objects themselves caring about how a particular query treats them. Obviously if the dates had a consistent semantic meaning I'd want them abstracted away, but we don't know that.

Comment: "Obviously if the dates had a consistent semantic meaning ..." I think the fact that we're sorting on the dates is sufficient evidence for a consistent semantic meaning. If there isn't a CSM then it makes no sense to sort the list by those fields. I feel that we're reaching a "We'll agree to disagree" point in our conversation mate.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier I chose this answer because I already have records in the database, so if I choose to add a new interface how will I deal with the records already stored before adding the interface ?

Comment: @the_ruby_racer: Dude, I've no idea how your ORM works or what effect  adding an interface might have. If you **absolutely cannot** add an interface or base class, you can still do this polymorphically, I'll add an answer detailing how.

Answer (score 2):

What I should have asked earlier is . . .

**What do you want to do after you've sorted them?**

The answer to this could have a big impact on the potential solution.

If the answer is something like *I need to display a list of the dates*, where you only need the dates in order. If so then you don't need to merge the two lists, you can get a sequence of just the ordered dates and use that e.g.

```
var orderedDates = networks.Select(n => n.NetworkingDate)
                   .Union(privateNetworks.Select(n => n.DateCreation))
                   .OrderBy(date => date);
```

If the answer is *I need to display a list of links showing the Date that links to the Id of the object, and something to identify the type of object*, then you could get away with something very like the above, with an Anonymous object.

```
var orderedDates = networks.Select(n => new {Date = n.NetworkingDate, Id = n.NetWorkingId, NetworkType = n.GetType().Name})
                   .Union(privateNetworks.Select(n => new {Date = n.DateCreation, Id = n.PrivateNetWorkingId, NetworkType = n.GetType().Name}))
                   .OrderBy(n => n.Date);
```

However if the answer is *I need to send a Shutdown() command to the 10 oldest networks* then **you really do need a polymorphic solution**, where you have a single type that you can call a `Shutdown()` method on, that will resolve to the specific `Shutdown()` method on the types you're using.

**A Polymorphic solution to use only if user [khellang's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13357392/joining-two-lists-of-different-types-and-sort-them-by-date/13357460#13357460) doesn't work for you**

From a comment on another answer

> @BinaryWorrier I chose this answer because I already have records in
>   the database, so if I choose to add a new interface how will I deal
>   with the records already stored before adding the interface ?

I find it difficult to believe that your ORM won't allow you to add an interface to an entity class and not - somehow - mark that interface and/or it's member so they're ignored by the ORM.

However, assuming you can't add a new interface or base class, you can still do this polymorphically.

Add the interface, add a class implementing the interface that for each of your Network classes (the `Abstractor` classes), then transform the network classes into `Abstractor` classes, adding them to a `List<INetwork>` and sorting that list.

```
public interface INetwork
{
    DateTime? Date { get; }
}

public class PrivateNetworkAbstractor
    :INetwork
{
    private PrivateNetwork network;
    public PrivateNetworkAbstractor(PrivateNetwork network)
    {
        this.network = network;
    }
    public DateTime? Date
    {
        get { return network.DateCreation; }
    }
}

public class NetworkingAbstractor
    : INetwork
{
    private Networking networking;
    public NetworkingAbstractor(Networking networking)
    {
        this.networking = networking;
    }
    public DateTime? Date
    {
        get { return networking.NetWorkingDate; }
    }
}
...

public IEnumerable<INetwork> MergenSort(IEnumerable<Networking> generalNetWorks, IEnumerable<PrivateNetwork> privateNetWorks)
{
    return generalNetWorks.Select(n => new NetworkingAbstractor(n)).Cast<INetwork>()
    .Union(privateNetWorks.Select(n => new PrivateNetworkAbstractor(n)).Cast<INetwork>())
    .OrderBy(n=> n.Date);
}
```

Comment: @KristianHellang: There was a time I knew the patterns book backwards, but I haven't opened it in years and now I remember the techniques but forget the name of the pattern, or forget that I learned the technique as a pattern. Boy do I wish my brain would work like it did 20 years ago . . .

Answer (score 1):

Create an interface that has the date and implement in in both classes. After that sorting is easy.

```
public interface INetwork
{
    DateTime? Date { get; }
}

public partial class Networking :EntityBase, INetwork
{
    public DateTime? Date
    {
        get { return NetWorkingDate; }
    }
}

public partial class PrivateNetwork :EntityBase, INetwork
{
    public DateTime? Date
    {
        get { return DateCreation; }
    }
}

var commonList = new List<INetwork>();
// Add instances of PrivateNetwork and Networking to the list

var orderedByDate = commonList.OrderBy(n => n.Date);
```

Answer (score 0):

First solution is using anonymous type

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Example1
{
    class Program
    {
        class Human
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Hobby { get; set; }
            public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        }
        class Animal
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string FavouriteFood { get; set; }
            public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var humans = new List<Human>
            {
                new Human
                {
                    Name = "Kate",
                    Hobby = "Fitness",
                    DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-27),
                },
                new Human
                {
                    Name = "John",
                    Hobby = "Cars",
                    DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-32),
                },
            };

            var animals = new List<Animal>
            {
                new Animal
                {
                    Name = "Fluffy",
                    FavouriteFood = "Grain",
                    DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2),
                },
                new Animal
                {
                    Name = "Bongo",
                    FavouriteFood = "Beef",
                    DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-6),
                },
            };

            var customCollection = (from human in humans
                                    select new
                                        {
                                            Name = human.Name,
                                            Date = human.DateOfBirth,
                                        }
                                        ).Union(from animal in animals
                                                select new
                                                    {
                                                        Name = animal.Name,
                                                        Date = animal.DateOfBirth,
                                                    }).OrderBy(x => x.Date);


            foreach (dynamic customItem in customCollection)
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Date: {0}, Name: {1}",      customItem.Date, customItem.Name));

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

or without anonymous type (created CustomClass):

```
...
class CustomClass
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        }
...
var customCollection = (from human in humans
                                    select new CustomClass
                                        {
                                            Name = human.Name,
                                            Date = human.DateOfBirth,
                                        }
                                        ).Union(from animal in animals
                                                select new CustomClass
                                                    {
                                                        Name = animal.Name,
                                                        Date = animal.DateOfBirth,
                                                    }).OrderBy(x => x.Date);


            foreach (CustomClass customItem in customCollection)
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Date: {0}, Name: {1}", customItem.Date, customItem.Name));

...
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply added a  base class and assigned it as the parent of both list's classes . and then simple did the union . it made the trick